# Changes to Batch script resulted in failure of ffprobe Bitrate reading

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-line, batch-processing

Okay here is a script that uses `ffprobe` to read the bitrate used in a video file. It takes a video as input, reads the video bitrate, and then proceeds to encode a (cropped) copy of the video using the same bitrate and x265 codec (as far as I can tell recoding is the only way to remove black boarders from videos from showing up in Icaros thumbnailer).

The script is executed from the windows explorer by right-clicking a video and choosing Transcode (command: cmd /k d:\utils\transcode.cmd "%1"). Everything else it does automatically.

```
@echo off
cd /d "%~dp0"
set "manifest=%~dpn0.txt"
set "temporary=%temp%\%~n0.tmp"
:: input must exist and be no duplicate
if exist "%~1" findstr /c:"%~1" "%manifest%" >nul || echo "%~1">>"%manifest%"
:: exit all but first instance
tasklist /fi "imagename eq handbrakecli.exe" | find /i "handbrakecli" && exit

:manifest
for /f "delims=" %%f in (%manifest%) do (
    set "in=%%~ff"
    set "out=%%~dpnf-2.mkv"
    call :transcode )
for %%a in ("%manifest%") do if not %%~za lss 4 goto :manifest
exit /b

:transcode
if not exist "%in%" goto :cleanup
if exist "%out%" goto :cleanup
    
ffprobe "%in%" -v 0 -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=bit_rate -print_format compact=p=0:nokey=1 >"%temporary%"
set /p bitrate=<%temporary%
if not defined bitrate echo failed to fetch bitrate & goto :cleanup
:: reduce to full kilobytes
set "bitrate=%bitrate:~0,-3%"
if %bitrate% gtr 7000 set bitrate=7000

HandBrakeCLI -i "%in%" -o "%out%" --encoder x265_10bit --vb %bitrate% --two-pass --turbo --audio 1-9 --aencoder copy --audio-copy-mask aac,ac3,mp2,mp3,opus --audio-fallback opus --ab 160 --drc 2.0

:cleanup
findstr /v /c:"%in%" "%manifest%">"%temporary%"
move /y "%temporary%" "%manifest%">nul
```

The command is solid, but it constantly keeps getting broken according to me working on the rest of the script. Please note that the `ffprobe` command itself, the variables etc has been constantly the same, but it still breaks every now and then. I suspect it has to do with `"` quotes or something similar somewhere else in the script. Currently, instead of a number representing the video track bitrate I get a `N/A`. And yes this has been tested on videos that have already been proven to work well with earlier script version, passing the bitrate info via `ffprobe`.

The %~n0.txt file looks like this

```
"D:\VIDEOS\SCOPITONE\Dario - Big Bang.mkv"
"D:\VIDEOS\SCOPITONE\Rossi - BB (edit).mp4"
```

See, instead of every launch of the script creating a separate encoding instance, a file is queued in this file. Only the first instance of the script is allowed to continue, and files added later will be processed from the end of the queue.

The file %temporary% is supposed to include the bitrate `2534533` and gets reduced to kilos by dropping the last three digits so `2534` would mean the new video will be coded with 2534k/s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processing lots of video files can take hours. It could happen that a shutdown of the PC or a restart of Windows must be done while the processing of one or more video files according to one or more existing list files is currently in progress. The list files with file or folder names not completely processed remain in the directory for temporary files on processing is interrupted and stopped for whatever reason. It should be possible to force a restart of the processing of the remaining video files according to the still existing list files later on processor time and power is available again for this video files processing task.

Below is the batch file from my initial answer with some enhancements.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "OutputNameExt=_2.mkv"
set "ExeFFProbe="
set "ExeHandBrake="

if not "%~1" == "" goto GetFFProbe
echo(
echo ERROR: "%~nx0" must be executed with at least one video file name!
echo(
if not defined NoPausePrompt set /P "=Press any key to exit ... " 0<nul & pause 1>nul
exit /B 2

:GetFFProbe
if defined ExeFFProbe if exist "%ExeFFProbe%" goto GetHandBrakeCLI
if exist "%~dp0ffprobe.exe" set "ExeFFProbe=%~dp0ffprobe.exe" & goto GetHandBrakeCLI
if exist ffprobe.exe for %%I in (ffrobe.exe) do set "ExeFFProbe=%%~fI" & goto GetHandBrakeCLI
for %%I in (ffprobe.exe) do set "ExeFFProbe=%%~$PATH:I"
if defined ExeFFProbe goto GetHandBrakeCLI
set "ExeMissing=ffprobe"
goto MissingEXE

:GetHandBrakeCLI
if defined ExeHandBrake if exist "%ExeHandBrake%" goto AddListFile
if exist "%~dp0HandBrakeCLI.exe" set "ExeHandBrake=%~dp0HandBrakeCLI.exe" & goto AddListFile
if exist HandBrakeCLI.exe for %%I in (HandBrakeCLI.exe) do set "ExeHandBrake=%%~fI" & goto AddListFile
for %%I in (HandBrakeCLI.exe) do set "ExeHandBrake=%%~$PATH:I"
if defined ExeHandBrake goto AddListFile
set "ExeMissing=HandBrakeCLI"

:MissingEXE
echo(
echo ERROR: "%~nx0" could not find the executable %ExeMissing%.exe!
echo(
echo Please make sure the program %ExeMissing%.exe is in the current directory or
echo can be found using the environment variable PATH or is in the directory:
echo(
echo "%~dp0"
echo(
if not defined NoPausePrompt set /P "=Press any key to exit ... " 0<nul & pause 1>nul
exit /B 3

:AddListFile
set "RetryCount=0"
set "ListFileName=%~n0"
set "ListFileName=%ListFileName:_= %"
set "ListFileName=%ListFileName:.= %_"
set "ListFullName=%TEMP%\%ListFileName%"
if /I "%~1" == "/ForceRestart" echo INFO: Force a restart of video files processing.& goto ProcessFiles
:GetFileNumber
set "FileNumber=0"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "eol=| tokens=2 delims=_." %%I in ('dir "!ListFullName!*.tmp" /A-D-H-L /B 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /R "_[0123456789][0123456789]*\.tmp$"') do if %%I GTR !FileNumber! set "FileNumber=%%I"
endlocal & set "FileNumber=%FileNumber%"
set /A FileNumber+=1
((for %%I in (%*) do echo("%~f1") 1>"%ListFullName%%FileNumber%.tmp") 2>nul
if not errorlevel 1 goto QueueTask
set /A RetryCount+=1
if not %RetryCount% == 50 goto GetFileNumber
echo(
echo ERROR: "%~nx0" could not create the temporary list file:
echo(
echo "%ListFullName%%FileNumber%.tmp"
echo(
if not defined NoPausePrompt set /P "=Press any key to exit ... " 0<nul & pause 1>nul
exit /B 1

:QueueTask
if not %FileNumber% == 1 exit /B
set "RetryCount=0"

:ProcessFiles
set "OneMoreList="
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%G in ('dir "%ListFullName%*.tmp" /A-D-H-L /B 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /R "_[0123456789][0123456789]*\.tmp$"') do (
    set "OneMoreList=1"
    set "LinesProcessed="
    (for /F "usebackq eol=| delims=" %%H in ("%TEMP%\%%G") do (
        if exist "%%~H\" (
            echo Processing *.mkv and *.mp4 in: %%H
            for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "%%~H\*.mkv" "%%~H\*.mp4" /A-D-L /B 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /E /I /L /V /C:"%OutputNameExt%"') do set "VideoFile=%%~H\%%I" & call :ProcessVideo
        ) else if exist "%%~H" set "VideoFile=%%~H" & call :ProcessVideo
        set "LinesProcessed=1"
    )) 2>nul
    if defined LinesProcessed (del "%TEMP%\%%G") else set /A RetryCount+=1
)
if not defined OneMoreList exit /B 0
if %RetryCount% LSS 50 goto ProcessFiles
echo(
echo ERROR: "%~nx0" could not process all the temporary list files:
echo(
echo "%ListFullName%*.tmp"
echo(
if not defined NoPausePrompt set /P "=Press any key to exit ... " 0<nul & pause 1>nul
exit /B 1

:ProcessVideo
for %%J in ("%VideoFile%") do (
    if exist "%%~dpnJ%OutputNameExt%" echo INFO: Skipping file: "%VideoFile%"& goto :EOF
    set "OutputFile=%%~nJ%OutputNameExt%"
    set "TempFile=%%~dpnJ.tmp"
)
echo Processing video: "%VideoFile%"
set "BitRate="
for /F %%J in ('^""%ExeFFProbe%" "%VideoFile%" -v 0 -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream^=bit_rate -print_format compact^=p^=0:nokey^=1 2^>nul^"') do set "BitRate=%%J"
if not defined BitRate echo ERROR: "%VideoFile%" is not a video file!& goto :EOF
set /A BitRate/=1000
if %BitRate% GTR 7000 set "BitRate=7000"
"%ExeHandBrake%" -i "%VideoFile%" -o "%TempFile%" --encoder x265_10bit --vb %BitRate% --two-pass --turbo --audio 1-9 --aencoder copy --audio-copy-mask aac,ac3,mp2,mp3,opus --audio-fallback opus --ab 160 --drc 2.0
if errorlevel 1 del "%TempFile%" 2>nul & goto :EOF
ren "%TempFile%" "%OutputFile%"
```

### 1. Customizable output file name extension

The third command line in the batch file is now:

```
set "OutputNameExt=_2.mkv"
```

This line defines the string which is appended to the source video file name without file extension to the output video file name. That makes it easily possible changing the output file names to `*_x265.mkv` or whatever seems to be best without doing a search and replace on entire batch file.

The string value of the environment variable `OutputNameExt` is referenced three times in the entire batch file.

### 2. Batch file option /ForceRestart

There is added in the command block below the label `:AddListFile` the command line:

```
if /I "%~1" == "/ForceRestart" echo INFO: Force a restart of video files processing.& goto ProcessFiles
```

That extension makes it possible running the batch file with the case-insensitive interpreted command line option `/ForceRestart` for restarting the processing of the video files according to the still existing list files in the directory for temporary files after a restart of Windows.

Running the batch file with the option `/ForceRestart` should be done only if there is no command process running which is already processing this batch file.

### 3. Information about processing videos in a directory

The following command line is added to the batch file for informing the user about the processing of videos in a directory.

```
echo INFO: Processing *.mkv and *.mp4 in: %%H
```

### 4. Ignoring videos in a directory having a file name with output name extension

The batch file could be started with one or more directory names which contain already several output videos created some time before. That can especially occur on stopping the video processing due to a necessary shutdown or restart of Windows and later force a restart of the video processing and one or more existing list files contain one or more directory names instead of just video file names.

It is also possible that a directory has multiple videos processed already before and later are added additional videos into the same directory which need to be processed too. This extension makes it possible to run the batch file with just the directory name to get processed now only all added video files and skipping the output videos created some time before in same directory.

This enhancement was done by extending the command line

```
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "%%~H\*.mkv" "%%~H\*.mp4" /A-D-L /B 2^>nul') do set "VideoFile=%%~H\%%I" & call :ProcessVideo
```

to the command line

```
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "%%~H\*.mkv" "%%~H\*.mp4" /A-D-L /B 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /E /I /L /V /C:"%OutputNameExt%"') do set "VideoFile=%%~H\%%I" & call :ProcessVideo
```

**FINDSTR** is used now for getting the list of video file names in the directory to process without the video file names ending case-insensitive with the output name extension as defined in the third line in the batch file.

It is nevertheless possible to process a video of which name ends with the string assigned to the environment variable `OutputNameExt`. But it is necessary to run the batch file with the name of such a video file as argument instead of the name of the directory containing such a video file.

### 5. Ignoring videos for which an appropriate output video already exists

There is added below the label `:ProcessVideo` the following command block:

```
for %%J in ("%VideoFile%") do (
    if exist "%%~dpnJ%OutputNameExt%" echo INFO: Skipping file: "%VideoFile%"& goto :EOF
    set "OutputFile=%%~nJ%OutputNameExt%"
    set "TempFile=%%~dpnJ.tmp"
)
```

This command block replaces the former last but one command line:

```
for %%J in ("%VideoFile%") do set "OutputFile=%%~dpnJ_2.mkv"
```

For each video file to process is checked now first if there is in the same directory already a video file with the output name extension as defined in the third command line. There is just output an information message about skipping this video file if there is already a matching output video file for the file to process next.

This enhancement is necessary as addition to the fourth enhancement to avoid processing of videos in a directory for which a matching output video already exists. It is also necessary for the use case of an interrupted and later restarted video processing on which multiple file names are stored in a list file and some of them have been processed already before interrupting the video files processing.

An already existing output video file must be explicitly deleted if a source video file has been modified somehow and there should be created the output video file once again using this batch file.

### 6. Using first a temporary file name as output file name

The fourth argument string passed to the program `HandBrakeCLI` is now a temporary file name.
There are appended also two more command lines at the bottom of the batch file.

```
if errorlevel 1 del "%TempFile%" 2>nul & goto :EOF
ren "%TempFile%" "%OutputFile%"
```

This enhancement deletes the temporary file created by `HandBrakeCLI` on `HandBrakeCLI` exited with an exit code greater or equal 1 indicating an error and the subroutine `ProcessFile` is exited without running the last command. That modified behavior is also useful if an error occurs on processing the source video file.

The last command line renames the created output file with the temporary file name to the correct output video file name as defined by the source file name and the string value assigned to the environment variable `OutputNameExt`.

That enhancement makes it possible to interrupt the video processing even while `HandBrakeCLI` is currently running resulting in a just partly done video processing task of the currently processed source video file. The just partly processed source video file is processed most likely first on restarting later the video processing by running the batch file with its option `/ForceRestart`.

Comment: still doesn't work after a windows reinstall

Answer (score 2):

The batch file should be designed according to the task description for running mainly just once even on being executed several times from *Windows File Explorer* within some seconds while the video processing task takes minutes. The batch file should append the passed file name of the video file to a list file while a video file is currently processed by first started batch file like a file names queue. This does not work for several reasons.

The first reason can be seen on creating a small batch file with the following lines:

```
@echo off
(echo File1.mkv& echo File2.mkv) >"%TEMP%\ListFile.tmp"
for /F "usebackq" %%I in ("%TEMP%\ListFile.tmp") do echo %%I& pause
del "%TEMP%\ListFile.tmp"
```

Run this batch file from within a command prompt window and there is output first:

```
File1.mkv
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Now open a second command prompt window and run the two command lines:

```
echo File3.mkv 1>>"%TEMP%\ListFile.tmp"
type "%TEMP%\ListFile.tmp"
```

The output is as expected:

```
File1.mkv
File2.mkv
File3.mkv
```

Switch back to the first command prompt window and press a key.

There is additionally output as expected:

```
File2.mkv
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Press again any key and see what happens next: **Nothing!**

The third file name appended in the meantime to the list file is not processed by first `cmd.exe` processing the batch file.

`for /f "delims=" %%f in (%manifest%) do (` results in opening the small list file by `cmd.exe` for reading its lines. There are read all lines at once from the list file on being small and copied into a local buffer and the list file is closed before running the commands in the **FOR** loop. It can happen for that reason that file names appended to the list file during processing of a video are never processed by first started `cmd.exe`.

The *Windows Command Processor* `cmd.exe` opens files like most Windows applications with exclusive file sharing access rights. That means no other process than the process opening the file first for read or write or read+write operations can also open the file or delete the file as long as being opened by the process.

The small list file is opened for reading all the file names for just a very short time. That makes it possible for `findstr.exe` opening the list file also for searching for a file name in the list file and makes it possible for second `cmd.exe` appending a file name to the list file while first `cmd.exe` is running the main **FOR** loop for processing the files as listed in the list file.

But it can happen also very easily that while first started `cmd.exe` is executing the commands in the batch with opening the list file for read or write for a very short time, another `cmd.exe` is started for processing the batch file with one more video file name as argument string and executing a command line like this one:

```
if exist "%~1" findstr /c:"%~1" "%manifest%" >nul || echo "%~1">>"%manifest%"
```

`findstr.exe` could fail to open the list file for reading the lines because of first `cmd.exe` has opened the list file at the same time for reading the lines too. The exit code returned by `findstr.exe` to `cmd.exe` is not 0 (success) in this case. The second `cmd.exe` should append now the file name to the list file but cannot open the list file for the write operation as perhaps still opened by first `cmd.exe`.

The usage of a single file for managing the video files to process is not working at all **by design** for that reason. It can work **by chance** but there is no guarantee by an appropriate coding design that the list file contents can be always updated as required or read at any time.

The solution in the batch file code posted below is using multiple list files for working around the file sharing access and file contents buffering problematic.

Another problematic command line in the batch file as posted in the question is:

```
tasklist /fi "imagename eq handbrakecli.exe" | find /i "handbrakecli" && exit
```

The executable `handbrakecli.exe` takes most of the time for processing a video file. But it can always happen that the first started `cmd.exe` processing the batch file `transcode.cmd` is currently processing other lines in the batch file or running executables like `ffprobe.exe` when a second `cmd.exe` is started and calls `tasklist.exe`. The executable `handbrakecli.exe` could have terminated itself and the process is removed from the task list by Windows just a few microseconds before `tasklist.exe` searches for this executable in the current task list. Then the second `cmd.exe` interprets the missing executable file name in the task list as no other `cmd.exe` is running for processing video files in the list file even if that is not true because of first `cmd.exe` is processing currently other command lines in the batch file or executing other executables like `ffprobe.exe`.

The batch file as posted below is designed for parallel execution of multiple `cmd.exe` all processing the same batch file as long as not too many are started at the same time within a second.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "ExeFFProbe="
set "ExeHandBrake="

if not "%~1" == "" goto GetFFProbe
echo(
echo ERROR: "%~nx0" must be executed with at least one video file name!
echo(
if not defined NoPausePrompt set /P "=Press any key to exit ... " 0<nul & pause 1>nul
exit /B 2

:GetFFProbe
if defined ExeFFProbe if exist "%ExeFFProbe%" goto GetHandBrakeCLI
if exist "%~dp0ffprobe.exe" set "ExeFFProbe=%~dp0ffprobe.exe" & goto GetHandBrakeCLI
if exist ffprobe.exe for %%I in (ffrobe.exe) do set "ExeFFProbe=%%~fI" & goto GetHandBrakeCLI
for %%I in (ffprobe.exe) do set "ExeFFProbe=%%~$PATH:I"
if defined ExeFFProbe goto GetHandBrakeCLI
set "ExeMissing=ffprobe"
goto MissingEXE

:GetHandBrakeCLI
if defined ExeHandBrake if exist "%ExeHandBrake%" goto AddListFile
if exist "%~dp0HandBrakeCLI.exe" set "ExeHandBrake=%~dp0HandBrakeCLI.exe" & goto AddListFile
if exist HandBrakeCLI.exe for %%I in (HandBrakeCLI.exe) do set "ExeHandBrake=%%~fI" & goto AddListFile
for %%I in (HandBrakeCLI.exe) do set "ExeHandBrake=%%~$PATH:I"
if defined ExeHandBrake goto AddListFile
set "ExeMissing=HandBrakeCLI"

:MissingEXE
echo(
echo ERROR: "%~nx0" could not find the executable %ExeMissing%.exe!
echo(
echo Please make sure the program %ExeMissing%.exe is in the current directory or
echo can be found using the environment variable PATH or is in the directory:
echo(
echo "%~dp0"
echo(
if not defined NoPausePrompt set /P "=Press any key to exit ... " 0<nul & pause 1>nul
exit /B 3

:AddListFile
set "RetryCount=0"
set "ListFileName=%~n0"
set "ListFileName=%ListFileName:_= %"
set "ListFileName=%ListFileName:.= %_"
set "ListFullName=%TEMP%\%ListFileName%"
:GetFileNumber
set "FileNumber=0"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "eol=| tokens=2 delims=_." %%I in ('dir "!ListFullName!*.tmp" /A-D-H-L /B 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /R "_[0123456789][0123456789]*\.tmp$"') do if %%I GTR !FileNumber! set "FileNumber=%%I"
endlocal & set "FileNumber=%FileNumber%"
set /A FileNumber+=1
((for %%I in (%*) do echo("%~f1") 1>"%ListFullName%%FileNumber%.tmp") 2>nul
if not errorlevel 1 goto QueueTask
set /A RetryCount+=1
if not %RetryCount% == 50 goto GetFileNumber
echo(
echo ERROR: "%~nx0" could not create the temporary list file:
echo(
echo "%ListFullName%%FileNumber%.tmp"
echo(
if not defined NoPausePrompt set /P "=Press any key to exit ... " 0<nul & pause 1>nul
exit /B 1

:QueueTask
if not %FileNumber% == 1 exit /B
set "RetryCount=0"

:ProcessFiles
set "OneMoreList="
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%G in ('dir "%ListFullName%*.tmp" /A-D-H-L /B 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /R "_[0123456789][0123456789]*\.tmp$"') do (
    set "OneMoreList=1"
    set "LinesProcessed="
    (for /F "usebackq eol=| delims=" %%H in ("%TEMP%\%%G") do (
        if exist "%%~H\" (
            for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "%%~H\*.mkv" "%%~H\*.mp4" /A-D-L /B 2^>nul') do set "VideoFile=%%~H\%%I" & call :ProcessVideo
        ) else if exist "%%~H" set "VideoFile=%%~H" & call :ProcessVideo
        set "LinesProcessed=1"
    )) 2>nul
    if defined LinesProcessed (del "%TEMP%\%%G") else set /A RetryCount+=1
)
if not defined OneMoreList exit /B 0
if %RetryCount% LSS 50 goto ProcessFiles
echo(
echo ERROR: "%~nx0" could not process all the temporary list files:
echo(
echo "%ListFullName%*.tmp"
echo(
if not defined NoPausePrompt set /P "=Press any key to exit ... " 0<nul & pause 1>nul
exit /B 1

:ProcessVideo
echo Processing video: "%VideoFile%"
set "BitRate="
for /F %%J in ('^""%ExeFFProbe%" "%VideoFile%" -v 0 -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream^=bit_rate -print_format compact^=p^=0:nokey^=1 2^>nul^"') do set "BitRate=%%J"
if not defined BitRate echo ERROR: "%VideoFile%" is not a video file!& goto :EOF
set /A BitRate/=1000
if %BitRate% GTR 7000 set "BitRate=7000"
for %%J in ("%VideoFile%") do set "OutputFile=%%~dpnJ_2.mkv"
"%ExeHandBrake%" -i "%VideoFile%" -o "%OutputFile%" --encoder x265_10bit --vb %BitRate% --two-pass --turbo --audio 1-9 --aencoder copy --audio-copy-mask aac,ac3,mp2,mp3,opus --audio-fallback opus --ab 160 --drc 2.0
```

The batch file defines with the first two command lines the required execution environment which is:

- Command echo mode turned off.
- Command extensions enabled as required.
- Delayed variable expansion disabled as required too.

Delayed variable expansion must be disabled to process correct video file names and folder paths containing one or more exclamation marks.

The third and fourth line undefine the two environment variables `ExeFFProbe` and `ExeHandBrake`. These two executables are not installed by default on Windows. The batch file expects them

- in the batch file directory or
- in the current working directory which can be any directory or
- in any directory as listed in string value of local environment variable `PATH`.

If the batch file fails to find one of these two executables, the user is informed about this error and the batch file exits with exit code 3 indicating this error to a parent batch file or process.

The two environment variables `ExeFFProbe` and `ExeHandBrake` can be used also by a batch file user to define the fully qualified file names of these two executables without having the executables in any of the searched directories.

I have not installed `ffprobe.exe` and `HandBrakeCLI.exe` at all. I used for testing purposes:

```
set "ExeFFProbe=C:\Temp\ffprobe.cmd"
set "ExeHandBrake=C:\Temp\HandBrakeCLI.cmd"
```

The file `C:\Temp\ffprobe.cmd` contained just the single command line:

```
@echo 582347
```

This batch file executed instead of `ffprobe.exe` simulated the output of the real executable according to information posted in the question.

The file `C:\Temp\HandBrakeCLI.cmd` contained just the two command lines:

```
@echo %0 %*
@pause
```

This batch file executed instead of `HandBrakeCLI.exe` simulated a long running executable where I could with a key press decide how long this batch file waits before its processing ends. I needed to insert on the last line in the main batch file `transcode.cmd` the command `call` left to `"%ExeHandBrake%"` for this executable simulation.

The batch file is designed for the execution with one **or more** argument strings. There is output an error message if the batch file is executed without any argument string, or the first argument string is an empty argument string passed to the batch file with `""`. The exit code is 2 in this usage error case.

The batch file can be executed with the arguments referencing one or more files or one or more folders containing `*.mkv` or `*.mp4` files with full path, without any path or a relative path. Empty arguments strings in the arguments list do not matter as long as the first argument strings is not `""`. The batch file could be run for that reason also with following arguments all specified on same command line executing the batch file:

```
"D:\VIDEOS\SCOPITONE\Dario - Big Bang.mkv" "D:\VIDEOS\SCOPITONE\Rossi - BB (edit).mp4" "" . "%USERPROFILE%\Videos"
```

The batch file processes in this case:

1. The file: `D:\VIDEOS\SCOPITONE\Dario - Big Bang.mkv`
2. The file: `D:\VIDEOS\SCOPITONE\Rossi - BB (edit).mp4`
3. It ignores the empty third argument string.
4. All files matched by the wildcard patterns `*.mkv` and `*.mp4` in the current working directory referenced with just `.` in the arguments list.
5. All files matched by the wildcard patterns `*.mkv` and `*.mp4` in the directory `%USERPROFILE%\Videos`.

Sometimes a batch file is executed by a user from within a command prompt window or called from within another batch file or run from within an executable. Halting the execution of a batch file with command **PAUSE** until a key is pressed is not wanted in such use cases. There can be defined the environment variable `NoPausePrompt` with any value outside of the batch file before starting it to prevent the user prompt if an error occurs.

The most important command lines are below the label `:AddListFile`.

The file name of the list file is derived from the batch file name. The batch file name should not contain an underscore or a dot in the file name without file extension because that would result in a not working code below which determines the file number between an underscore and the file extension `.tmp` in all of the list files created by this batch file on multiple executions of the batch file within a short time. The few command lines below the label `:AddListFile` makes that sure although some of them are not needed with batch file name `transcode.cmd`.

The batch file is designed for being stored in a directory which is write-protected for the current user. That is simply a good coding design as executables and scripts are often stored in directories which are write-protected for standard users.

The batch file does not append all argument strings (file or folder names) to a single list file created in the directory for temporary files as that could fail as described above. It searches instead in the directory for temporary files for list files created by this batch file which have a file number between an underscore and the file extension `.tmp`. The greatest file number of all currently existing list files is assigned to the environment variable `FileNumber` if at least one list file exists at all.

The greatest file number of the existing list files is incremented by one and all the argument strings are written into a new list file with the new file number in file name left to the file extension. The used syntax results in creating first the new list file and open it, write all the passed argument strings **with** surrounding `"` with fully qualified file/folder name into the list file and then close the list file. But on asynchronous calls of the batch file another `cmd.exe` could do that exactly at the same time resulting in a file sharing access denied error condition. In most cases the file creation will be successful, and the processing of the batch file is continued therefore below the label `:QueueTask`.

But it can happen that `cmd.exe` failed opening the new list file for writing all the arguments strings with the surrounding `"` into this file. The *Windows Command Processor* outputs an error message in this case which is redirected to device **NUL** to suppress it. The environment variable `RetryCount` is incremented by one in this error case which occurs most likely very rare. Then the entire process to get currently greatest file number in all list files in the directory for temporary files with writing the argument strings next into a new list file with an incremented file number is executed once again. There should be no problem anymore on second run.

However, it is possible that the disk is full or the MFT (Master File Table) of NTFS or RealFS or the FAT (File Allocation Table) of FAT32 or exFAT cannot be updated for one more file in the directory for temporary files. The result would be a very long running loop until a file is deleted somewhere on storage media or in the directory for temporary files. That is the reason for the condition to exit the loop after 50 retries and inform the user about this very unusual problem.

Below the label `:QueueTask` is first checked if the new file number is **not** 1 which means that there is at least one list file in the directory for temporary files created by the batch file. Another `cmd.exe` must be still running processing this list file. The current `cmd` process can exit for that reason as the new list file will be processed by the other `cmd.exe` processing the same batch file.

The code below the label `ProcessFiles` is processing the list files and the videos. All that code below this label is executed only by first `cmd.exe` started for processing the batch file while no other running `cmd.exe` does that too.

The first **FOR** loop loads into memory of `cmd.exe` the names of all currently existing list files created by this batch file. Then one list file after the other is opened for reading the lines which are fully qualified file or folder names, or an empty line ignored by **FOR** if there was an empty argument string in the arguments list on starting the batch file execution.

There must be considered the file sharing access denied error condition if one of the list files is opened by another application at the same time. That can be also an anti-virus application processing a temporary list file for scanning it for potential threads, or a user who opened one of the list files in a text editor for viewing its contents, or another `cmd.exe` processing that batch file. The error message output by `cmd` on failed opening of a list file is redirected to device **NUL** to suppress it. In such a very rare use case no line could be read from the list file which results in keeping this list file and incrementing instead the value of the environment variable `RetryCount`. There should be never a list file containing just empty lines.

In most cases opening the list file works and reading the lines is possible. The code of the inner **FOR** loop checks first if the name read from the current list file is an existing directory and in this case are all `*.mkv` and `*.mp4` files processed in this directory. It is checked otherwise if the name read from the current list file is a file which is processed next. Not existing files/folders are silently ignored.

There are processed all list files found on first **FOR** loop runs in background another `cmd.exe` to get the list of list file names which are all deleted if they could be all opened and read successfully. But it could happen that the batch file was executed in the meantime several times with adding more list files. The entire command block is executed once more for that reason until `OneMoreList` is kept undefined because of not finding anymore any list file created by this batch file in the directory for temporary files.

But it could happen that `cmd.exe` fails repeatedly opening one of the list files in the directory for temporary files because of another application has opened the temporary list file for a longer time for whatever reason. That would result in an endless running loop. The environment variable `RetryCount` is used to exit the loop on 50 or more retries have been already done with no success processing all list files created by this batch file in the directory for temporary files. The user is informed about this very unlikely error condition.

The processing of a video file in the subroutine `ProcessVideo` is quite simple. There is first undefined the environment variable `BitRate`. Then `ffprobe.exe` is executed with one more `cmd.exe` started in background to determine the bit rate and output it. The output is captured and assigned to the environment variable `BitRate`.

Well, it could be that the name of a file passed to the batch file is not a video file at all. In this case `ffprobe.exe` outputs most likely no bit rate value but an error message which is redirected to device **NUL** by the background command process. An error message is output on bit rate is still undefined after execution of `ffprobe.exe` and the subroutine is exited with `goto :EOF`. There should be added the command line `if "%BitRate%" == "N/A" echo ERROR: Bit rate of "%VideoFile%" could not be determined!& goto :EOF` if `ffprobe.exe` outputs the string `N/A` to standard output handle **STDOUT** in case of the file is not a video file or `ffprobe.exe` failed to determine the bit rate value because of unknown video encoding.

The bit rate is divided otherwise by 1000. The bit rate is set to 7000 on resulting bit rate is greater than 7000.

Next the output file name is determined for the current video file by appending `_2` left to the file extension and changing the file extension to `.mkv` on video file having a different file extension like `.mp4`.

**Note:** The batch file does not exclude processing video files of which file names end already with `_2.mkv`. The user should avoid passing a folder name to the batch file containing already output video files or the batch file is extended to ignore such video file names.

The last line of the subroutine calls the executable `HandBrakeCLI.exe` for recoding the video file which can take some time.

The batch file `transcode.cmd` should be never executed directly from *Windows File Explorer*. There should be created a shortcut file with file name `Transcode.lnk` or whatever is preferred by the user. The shortcut file should be stored in the directory `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo`. My answer on [drag and drop files onto the batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75714143/3074564) explains step by step how to create such a shortcut file.

The shortcut property **Target** should be:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /C C:\SCRIPTS\transcode.cmd
```

The fully qualified batch file name can be of course different. It is important that the full batch file name does not contain a space or one of these characters `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ `` because of that would require enclosing the batch file name in `"`. But the started *Windows Command Processor* would fail to interpret the argument strings correct if the batch file name is enclosed in quotation marks and the *Windows File Explorer* appends on usage of the shortcut one or more file/folder names also enclosed in `"` because of the full file/folder name contains also a space or one of these characters `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ ``.

The shortcut property **Start in** can be `%SystemRoot%` or is kept empty for using the current working directory of the *Windows File Explorer*.

All other shortcut properties like the **Comment**, the icon displayed in context menu **Send to** of *Windows File Explorer*, the font, font size, number of rows and columns, etc. can be configured as wanted. This is one big advantage of using a shortcut instead of the batch file directly. Nearly all the properties for the console window can be defined in the shortcut file while the direct execution results in running `%ComSpec% /c "%USERPROFILE%\transcode.cmd"` and the file/folder names with the console properties as defined under registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console`.

The file name of the shortcut file without file extension `.lnk` is displayed as context menu item on right clicking on a file or folder in *Windows File Explorer* and opening the context submenu **Send to** after clicking on **Show more options** on Windows 11. Its properties are read by `explorer.exe` which calls next the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) with the command line as defined with shortcut property **Target** whereby `explorer.exe` appends:

- the fully qualified file name of the active file if the right click was done on a file, or
- the fully qualified file names of the selected files if the right click was done on a list of selected files, or
- the fully qualified directory name of the active directory if the right click was done on a directory, or
- the fully qualified directory names of the selected directories if the right click was done on a list of selected directories.

**Note:** There is the command line length limitation of 8192 characters (with terminating null). It is therefore not possible selecting thousands of files and clicking on the context menu item to let `explorer.exe` pass all the files names to `cmd.exe` and further to the batch file for processing all those files.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?`
- `cmd /?`
- `del /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `exit /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

See also [single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) for an explanation of the unconditional command operator `&`.

PS: The batch file does not check if being called with a file name which exists already in one of the currently existing list files. That makes not much sense in my opinion as it is always possible that a video file has been processed already in the past and the list file is already deleted which contained the file name of this video. Then the video is processed nevertheless a second time even of adding a search for a file name in all currently existing list files.