# Extract part of filename and execute command from context menu

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I added context menu that uses selected files on the batch script

context menu registry uses:

```
"C:\test\yr.bat" "%~1"
```

I like to extract 11 characters between the square brackets and use itwithn `yt-dlp`.

Sample file list, file extension, and variable location is the same for all files.

```
academffo-nonpo- [pFqW8usdsXf].docx
acadeffo-nonpo- [gFqW8usd6Xf].docx
acadeffo-nonpo- [mFqW8dsd-Xf].docx
academyo-fdfddd- [MFqW8uRdsXf].docx
acadfff-ddrrrd- [mQqW8uydsXf].docx
academff-nonpo- [-FqW8usdsXf].docx
a 스핑크스 [-ERSqcqqcqo].docx
[직] 0710 밴디트(am) [b8srkgrRr0w].docx
```

1st try

```bash
@/start "" for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%A in ("%~1") do set "bracket_value=%%A"
yt-dlp --force-overwrites -S res:360 "%bracket_value %"
```

2nd try

```bash
@/echo off "" for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%A in ("%~1") do set "bracket_value=%%A"
do (
yt-dlp --force-overwrites -S res:360 "%bracket_value %"
```

It is able to extract the variables, but is not using them with the `yt-dlp` command.

Comment: Why are you `start`ing the `for` loop? Don't do that; that spawns the command in a separate process so the variable won't exist in the main script. Also, you wrote `%bracket_value %`, which has an extra space in it so you're calling the wrong variable.

Comment: new to bat and still not working https://imgur.com/76ZOeLB

Comment: All that screenshot shows is that your variable doesn't have a value, but the code that you've posted has multiple typos in it that you may or may not have fixed correctly based on my previous comment and without seeing what you tried, I can't tell you where you failed.

Comment: ```@echo off 
    for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%a in ("%~1") do set "bracketValue=%%~a"
    yt-dlp --force-overwrites -S res:360 "%bracketValue%"
    pause
```

Comment: Yes, that code works correctly in my tests.

Comment: Yap but the issue is most of the time it didn't work. ```a 스핑크스 [-ERSqcqqcqo].docx``` generate -E as bracketValue.
```[직] 0710 밴디트(am) [b8srkgrRr0w].docx``` generate 직 as bracketValue

Comment: At no point in your question did you even hint at the possibility of other brackets or non-Latin characters in the filename. Look at the example filenames you gave. That's the only information we have to work with.

Comment: Sorry, added more examples to the question. How to solve this issue?

Comment: ```@For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=2 Delims=[]" %%G In ("%~1") Do @P:\athTo\yt-dlp.exe --force-overwrites -S res:360 "%%~G"``` seems a likely one line batch file example.

Comment: BTW, if you are not really using a file with a list of files in it, then my previous example would have been, ```@For /F "Tokens=2 Delims=[]" %%G In ("%~1") Do @P:\athTo\yt-dlp.exe --force-overwrites -S res:360 "%%~G"```. I should mention however that your last example in the file list shows more than one pair of square brackets, which would identify `직` as the result. This is because you are using a set number of tokens and delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

There can be used for this task the following **commented** batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
rem If the batch file is executed without any argument string or the first
rem argument string is an empty string then just exit without doing anything.
if "%~1" == "" exit /B
for %%I in (%*) do set "FileName=%%~nI" & call :ProcessFile
exit /B

:ProcessFile
rem Get from the current file name just everything after first [.
set "BracketValue=%FileName:*[=%"
rem Ignore this file if its file name ends with [ left to the file extension.
if not defined BracketValue goto :EOF
rem Check if the string assigned to variable BracketValue does not still
rem contain an opening square bracket because of the file name contains
rem that character multiple times. In this case process the file name
rem once more as done before until the remaining string contains no [.
if not "%BracketValue:[=%" == "%BracketValue%" set "FileName=%BracketValue%" & goto ProcessFile
rem Remove the last character on being a closing square bracket as expected.
if "%BracketValue:~-1%" == "]" set "BracketValue=%BracketValue:~0,-1%"
rem Ignore the file if there is no string left because of
rem the file name ends with [] left to the file extension.
if not defined BracketValue goto :EOF
rem Ignore the file if the bracket value has less than 11 characters.
if "%BracketValue:~10,1%" == "" goto :EOF
rem Ignore the file if the bracket value has more than 11 characters.
if not "%BracketValue:~11,1%" == "" goto :EOF
yt-dlp.exe --force-overwrites -S res:360 "%BracketValue%"
goto :EOF
```

It would be best to extend `yt-dlp.exe` with the full path and enclose the fully qualified file name in `"` on containing a space or one of these characters `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ ``.

The batch file could be stored in the directory `%USERPROFILE%` with the file name `YouTubeDownloader.cmd`. Hint: Do not use the file extension `.bat` for batch files processed by the *Windows Command Processor* `cmd.exe`.

The batch file is designed for processing even multiple files of which file names are passed to it as arguments on starting the batch file execution.

```
YouTubeDownloader.cmd "academffo-nonpo- [pFqW8usdsXf].docx" "" "academff-nonpo- [-FqW8usdsXf].docx"
```

result in execution of

```
yt-dlp.exe --force-overwrites -S res:360 "pFqW8usdsXf"
yt-dlp.exe --force-overwrites -S res:360 "-FqW8usdsXf"
```

with ignoring the second argument string being an empty argument string as passed with `""` to the batch file in the example command line.

Please read my answer on [drag and drop files onto the batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75714143/3074564) explaining step by step how to create a shortcut file finally stored in the directory `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo` for running the batch file with one or more file names via the **Send to** context menu of the *Windows File Explorer*. The property **Target** of the shortcut must be:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /C "%USERPROFILE%\YouTubeDownloader.cmd"
```

The shortcut property **Start in** must be empty. *Explorer* sets the directory containing the (selected) file(s) as current working directory on using the **Send to** context menu item as defined by the shortcut on calling the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) for execution of the *Windows Command Processor* with its options `/D` and `/C` and the fully qualified batch file name and the file names of the (selected) file(s) appended as additional arguments processed by the batch file.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?`
- `cmd /?`
- `echo /?`
- `exit /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Please read [single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) for an explanation of the unconditional command operator `&` used twice in the batch file too.

PS: The processing of the batch file can be speed up a little bit by removing all lines beginning with the remark command `rem` and the single empty line and the last `goto :EOF`.