# Batch file no longer works correctly in Windows 11

Tags: batch-file, explorer

I have a batch file that I run in the File Explorer address line that moves files from a specific directory into the current File Explorer directory.

```bash
move C:\Specific folder\*.* .
```

I run it by clicking the blank space at the end of the address which causes the pieces of the name of the folder to combine into a single path string and become selected. At this point, I type in the name of the batch file, hit Enter, and it executes, placing the files from the specific folder into the one I'm currently looking at.

This previously worked perfectly for years under Windows 10, but in Windows 11, the files are copied into the batch file parent directory instead.

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: You should provide the code here so that someone can help. As is, there is no way to know what you're trying to do or why it's not working. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Try to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78243826/edit) your question and add your batch code otherwise this question will be closed and nobody can answer you.

Comment: Clicking the empty space in an Explorer window does not, and never has, run a batch file, _it only higlights the directory path, as you've mentioned_. You need to revisit your question, and add all of the information we need to understand the exact process you are undertaking, so that we can replicate it, _(and therefore assist you)_.

Comment: `move C:\Specific folder\*.* .` worked never in any Windows. That command line results in the error output: `The syntax of the command is incorrect.` The reason is passing three space separated arguments to the internal command __MOVE__ of `cmd.exe` which expects only two arguments. `move /Y "C:\Specific folder\*" .` or just `move "C:\Specific folder\*" .` would work if the current directory referenced with `.` is really the directory passed by `explorer.exe` to the kernel function `CreateProcess` on starting `%ComSpec% /c "C:\Full Path\BatchFile.cmd"`.

Comment: Please read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75714143/3074564) with detailed instructions on how to create a shortcut file with a file name like `Move Files` for your task in the `SendTo` folder. The shortcut property __Target__ must be for your task `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /C move /Y "C:\Specific folder\*"`. If you right click now on a folder in *Windows File Explorer* and click in context submenu __Send to__ on item `Move Files`, `explorer.exe` calls `CreateProcess` for execution of `cmd.exe` with the specified arguments and the directory name appended as last argument.

Comment: Another method to add a context menu for moving the files into a right clicked directory (and only directory, not files) is described in full details in my answer on [What's the meaning of "NoWorkingDirectory" string value in Windows Registry?](https://superuser.com/a/1736858/971324) It is possible to register the execution of `cmd.exe` for moving the files into a right clicked directory in Windows registry as special action for directories. That solution would not need an additional file like a batch file or a shortcut file.

Comment: I have edited the question as requested, but it is still showing up as closed, with the blue box telling me to edit it.

Comment: It still doesn't make sense. If the address bar text is highlighted and you type the name of the batch file, you simply replace that text with your new text. Nothing else happens or runs unless you do something else, like click the mouse, or press a key. Where and what are you 'combining'? Please provide us with an example of what is in the address bar initially, and what is in the bar after typing.

Comment: If you click into the address bar of *Windows File Explorer* and append a backslash and the batch file name to the displayed directory path and press key ENTER or RETURN, you do nothing else than executing the batch file in this directory if existing in this directory at all. That is practically the same as copying the batch file into the current displayed directory and double clicking on it for execution in that directory.

Comment: If you click into the address bar and replace the displayed directory path by the batch file name and press key ENTER or RETURN, you execute the batch file which must be found with the environment variables `PATH` and `PATHEXT` as described by [What is the reason for "X is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41461002/3074564) The batch file was stored in a folder which was in environment variable `PATH` if that worked on Windows 10 and is not in a folder of environment variable `PATH` on not working on Windows 11.